# Matches of numbers into another array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have to put into an integer for matches in the numbers of an array and another array, which do not have the same position in the array.
For example: I have these two Arrays of numbers:

```
4578
7539
```

It means that it have 1 number in the same position (5), and the number 7 is in the first array but not in the same position, so this case must increment 1 in my integer.

If it is in the same position like the number 5, I did this:

```
int introducido = Integer.parseInt(numero.getText());
for (int i = 0; i < String.valueOf(introducido).length(); i++) {
    int entero = Integer.parseInt("" + numero.getText().charAt(i));
    String temp = Integer.toString(numAleatorio);
    int intarrNumeros = Integer.parseInt("" + temp.charAt(i));
    if (intarrNumeros == entero) {
        fijas++;
    }
```

But I don't know how to do if is not in the same position.

Comment: I cannot understand your requirement.... :(

Comment: Is this a class assignment?  See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**
Working for non-unique symbols in input strings

Try this code

```
    pattern = "4578 ";
    String toFind = "7539";

    int samePosition = 0;
    int notSamePosition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < toFind.length(); ++i) {
        char digit = toFind.charAt(i);
        if (pattern.contains(String.valueOf(digit))) {
            if (pattern.charAt(i) == digit) {
                ++samePosition;
            } else {
                ++notSamePosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `7777` for `pattern` and `toFind` and see if it returns 4 for `samePosition`.

Comment: I think digits in string must be unique. It seems like "Bulls and cows" game.

Comment: In your code they need to be unique, yes, but OP hasn't mentioned something about unique numbers.

Comment: It works now, thanks, the key is the pattern.contains to check if the number is in the array. Thanks, solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the argument in the if statement to not equals.

```
if (intarrNumeros != entero)
```

Comment: Sorry didn't understood me. I mean that if the number is IN THE ANOTHER ARRAY but not in the same position, increase 1 into a variable. For example: 1234 and 4321, there are the same numbers but not in the same position, so in another variable (not in picas++), must increase 1, so picas have 0 and the other variable (fijas), have 4.

Comment: In that case you will need to loop through everything in the second array and check if the number exists there. Or you can do a search on the second array.